# Gmail is sending me emails late

Tags: gmail

I received an email at 7:09am this morning about a Facebook login alert. However, when I opened the email, it was for a login I made on my phone the day before in the afternoon (around 3:29pm).

When I opened the email, the date in the top right hand corner was the same time as the login.

What causes this lag in delivery?

Comment: Is it just this one email and Facebook? Or is it frequently with other emails?

Comment: @Eight Days of Malaise (I love your name, btw) - AFAIK, it was only a Facebook problem, and it came and went. I do remember the night before I logged out and in of Facebook on my Macbook and phone more than once around 5pm and 8pm, and I instantaneously got the login alert emails.

Comment: Then it is most probably a problem on Facebook's side, or at least in the delivery of messages between Facebook and Gmail's servers. As such, it has very little to do with the Gmail web app. Therefore, your question looks off-topic for [webapps.se].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mail delivery.

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessarily Gmail's fault. There's no "guarantee" for when email is supposed to get where it's going. By its nature, it could take a number of varying paths to get to its destination. It may actually pass through dozens of servers on its way to you and could be delayed on any one of them. Maybe a server had a hard drive failure before the message could be sent, or it was brought down for maintenance, or a switch was pulled offline, or there was a huge backlog of messages (spam) being processed. There's really no way to know. The message headers may show some clues as to where the delay was, but not necessarily. We've grown spoiled by near-instantaneous email delivery, but it wasn't always that way, nor is there a requirement that it be so.